# SuluArticleBundle throws undefined index: article

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, sulu

I'm trying to setup the SuluArticleBundle with ElasticSearch 2.4. I'm following the [documentation](https://github.com/sulu/SuluArticleBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md) but I keep getting

`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Notice: Undefined index: article`

when running the `php bin/console assets:install`command

This is the first time I'm using ElasticSearch and the SuluArticleBundle so I'm not sure if it's an error related to my ElasticSearch setup or the bundle setup.

Any idea what the problem might be?

**Edit**

This is the stack trace

`Exception trace:
 () at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/sulu/article-bundle/DependencyInjection/SuluArticleExtension.php:253
 Sulu\Bundle\ArticleBundle\DependencyInjection\SuluArticleExtension->appendArticlePageConfig() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/sulu/article-bundle/DependencyInjection/SuluArticleExtension.php:207
 Sulu\Bundle\ArticleBundle\DependencyInjection\SuluArticleExtension->load() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:66
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:39
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:143
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:746
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:576
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:118
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:65
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:125
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/bin/console.php:23
 include() at /Users/jaimy/projects/student-starter/bin/console:21`

**Edit #2**

This is my `sulu_core` config

```
# SuluCore Configuration
sulu_core:
    webspace:
        config_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/webspaces"
    content:
        structure:
            default_type:
                snippet: "article_default"
            paths:
                homepage:
                    path: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/templates/pages"
                    type: "home"
                page:
                    path: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/templates/pages"
                    type: "page"
                snippet:
                    path: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/templates/snippets"
                    type: "snippet"
                article:
                    path: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/templates/articles"
                    type: "article"
```

Comment: Can you call the command with the `-v` flag and post the stack trace? Then i can see which line causes the issue! Did you use the newest version of SuluArticleBundle?

Comment: Have you also configured the `sulu_core` with the new pathes? see: https://github.com/sulu/SuluArticleBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md#configure-suluarticlebundle-and-sulu-core

Comment: I've added the stack trace to the question. Yeah I'm using the latest version of the ArticleBundle.
I've not yet configured the `sulu_core`. Might that solve my problem? I haven't done that yet because I'm walking through the install docs in order.

Comment: i think that would solve the issue - maybe the docs could be improve in that point 

Comment: I'm so sorry, I was looking at competely the wrong branch of my project. I did in fact configure the `sulu_core`. Exactly like described in the docs.

Comment: so you have configured it correctly?

Comment: Yes I have the exact same configuration as in the docs.

Comment: can you also post you configuration of `sulu_core`? do you have multiple `sulu_core` sections in a single config.yml file?

Comment: Ah yes I now see that I have multiple `sulu_core` sections in my config file. I'll merge them and let you know how that works out. If the error still occurs, I'll post my config.

Comment: Still get the error so I've posted my config.

Comment: is this configuration in the file app/config/config.yml? could you please correct the indemtation?

Comment: I hope this is better? This is the way I have it setup in my app/config/config.yml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed the default_type configuration for the article. please add the config at `sulu_core.content.structure.default_type.article`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help! That was the problem. Stupid mistake. Thanks again!